# use `collection.updateOne({id}, {$addToSet: {pictures: picture}}, {upsert: true});`, why do I have two pieces of data with the same id in my database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I use `collection.updateOne({id}, {$addToSet: {pictures: picture}}, {upsert: true});` to update existed data based on id or insert the data, but I found two pieces of data with the same id in my database.I expect that when I find that there is already data for this id, I will update the data instead of adding it.

Is it caused by concurrent requests？

```
app.get('/aaa', async (req, res) => {
    await client.connect();
    const {id, picture} = req.query;
    const collection = client.db('abc').collection('bcd');
    await collection.updateOne({id}, {$addToSet: {pictures: picture}}, {upsert: true});
    res.send('response');
});
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/aaa?id=1&picture=000');
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/aaa?id=1&picture=111');
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/aaa?id=2&picture=123');
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/aaa?id=3&picture=123');
}, []);
```

I tested it with the demo above and it didn't recur.